# ElasticSearch does not find results with umlaut (two different ascii for the same character)

Tags: elasticsearch

Exist two different ascii numbers for umlaut "ö" characters

1. (ö) 111 204 136
2. (ö) 195 182

when i query for search value i don't get the result with (ö) 111 204 136 characters. Why the elastic search does not find the sentences with the first ascii? It works only for the second character.

Here is my index config:

```
[
                    'filter'=> [
                      'custom_ascii_folding' => [
                          'type' => 'asciifolding',
                           'preserve_original' => true,
                      ],
                        'german_stop' => [
                            'type' => 'stop',
                            'stopwords' => '_german_',
                        ],
                        'german_keywords' => [
                            'type' => 'keyword_marker',
                            'keywords' => [
                                0 => 'Beispiel',
                            ],
                        ],
                        'german_stemmer' => [
                            'type' => 'stemmer',
                            'language' => 'light_german',
                        ],
                    ],
                    'analyzer' => [
                        'default' => [
                            'type' => 'custom',
                            'tokenizer' => 'all',
                            'filter'=>  [
                                "custom_ascii_folding",
                                "lowercase",
                                'classic',
                                "german_stop",
                                "german_keywords",
                                "german_normalization",
                                "german_stemmer"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ],
                    'tokenizer' => [
                        'all' => [
                            'type' => 'edge_ngram',
                            'min_gram' => 2,
                            'max_gram' => 40,
                            'token_chars' => [
                                'letter',
                                'digit',
                                'symbol',
                                'punctuation',
                                'whitespace'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
```

I tried to add german_normalization but it does not work.

The problem can exist for other special german characters. I solved the same problem in postgres search by unaccent() function.

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) only has 128 code points, none of which is the umlaut or ö.  What exactly do you mean by saying those are two ASCII numbers for "ö"?